# How can I detect invalid JSON containing a trailing comma with c#?

Tags: c#, json

Yes, yes, I know that there are countless posts about detecting invalid Json.  They all say the same thing: Try parsing or de-serializing the object.  Guess what?  In this case, Json.NET happily parses my malformed JSON and doens't complain.  I think that I need to clarify:  The only thing wrong with my JSON is a trailing comma in an array.  The following illustrates my problem:

```
string badJson = "{ 'array' : [ {'objName1' : 'value1'}, {'objName2' : 'value2'}, {'objName3' : 'value3'}, ] }";

var obj = JObject.Parse(badJson);
```

The JSON isn't valid in a browser as it has a trailing comma in the array, but it's happily parsed into a jobject.  Since I can't actually use serialization to detect this problem, how can I?

Note that I've tried serializing into an object, that produced the same result.

Update:

The following code will detect the comma correctly and strip it, in case anyone needs to do this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(.*?),\s*(\}|\])",(RegexOptions.Multiline));

var cleanJson = regex.Replace(content, m => String.Format("{0} {1}",m.Groups[1].Value,m.Groups[2].Value));
```

Another possible solution would be to use the .NET Json parser with my object model.  Another solution that worked for me was to parse the object into a Jobject then serialize it again.  That allowed me to use the Json where I needed to.  This was much slower than the above regex, so I ultimately used the regex.

Comment: Why don't you use another json parser to detect it. `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(badJson)`

Comment: @L.B Are you pretty sure that the MS supplied library would detect the trailing comma?  I can try this.

Comment: What I've done is de-serialize then serialize the data in question, providing me with valid json that I can send back to the browser.  This worked out and required two lines to fix.

Comment: Nathan, but your question was about detecting invalid json. That is a different thing.

Comment: @L.B FWIW, your solution works also, I just tried it.  The JavaScriptSerializer correctly detects the invalid JSON and gives me an exception.  I'm not sure which I'm going to use, but thanks!

Comment: @L.B you're right.  When I asked the question, I had it in my head that what I needed was to detect the problem.  As I was looking at it, I realized that sanitizing the Json would work out for me also.  Thanks for your input, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if Regex.IsMatch(badJson, "^.*,\s*]\s*}$") 
   throw new Exception("hey that's bad json");
```

Comment: What I've done is de-serialize then serialize the data in question, providing me with valid json that I can send back to the browser.  This worked out and required two lines to fix, rather than my spending an hour writing a super complex regex that would work for every case and never give a false positive.

Comment: I accepted your answer because after I thought about it I realized that your solution would solve the problem, with the following modification: /.*?,(:?\s*]|\s*})/

Comment: The regex solution I detailed in my answer turned out to be way faster than deserializing then serializing the json, so thanks for the suggestion, a regex is what's going into production.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip out the offending comma with a regular expression.

```
Regex.Replace(badJson, "}\s*,+\s*]", "} ]");
```

This pattern will find a comma between a closing brace and a closing bracket with an arbitrary (0 or more) quantity of whitespace characters surrounding the comma.

Comment: Unfortunately that's totally out of the question.  The object I'm dealing with is HUGE and very complex and deserializes into a very complex object schema.

Comment: But wouldn't all instances of the sequence `}, ]` be incorrect?  So it would be good to catch them all, no?

Comment: i dont understand how complexity of an object schema makes regex.replace inappropriate...

Comment: You can use `^.*,\s*]\s*}$` if you're only worried about the trailing comma at the end of the string.

Comment: ... if you want to throw an exception or something instead of fixing the problem, you could do a regex.ismatch instead...

Comment: How about a trailing comma at the end of a false, true, null, string, array, object or ... Any of the other cases that can have a trailing comma that's invalid?  I guess you're right, a regex could catch all of those scenarios.

Comment: { 'data': true,} [ 'data','data',] [false,true,] and ["data", "data",] are three examples that won't work with your regex.  I might try writing a regex which could catch each and every case which could happen, I guess.

Comment: What I've done is de-serialize then serialize the data in question, providing me with valid json that I can send back to the browser.  This worked out and required two lines to fix, rather than my spending an hour writing a super complex regex that would work for every case and never give a false positive.

Comment: The regex only finds this pattern: } <some whitespace> , <some whitespace> ], so it wouldn't need to be more complicated as none of your examples match that pattern.  Nonetheless, good that you found a workable solution. :)

Comment: @PeterGluck Yes, yes.  After thinking about it I realized that a regex would work.  Robert's regex, however, is the one I'd need.  In no case do I ever want a trailing comma followed by a closing } or ].  Yours wouldn't work for true, or false, as I mentioned in my previous comment.