# JSON.NET allows malformed JSON during deserialization

Tags: json, json.net

I am stunned -- but perhaps because I am uninformed -- that `JsonConvert.Deserialize<>()` will parse this malformed JSON without complaint:

```
{"Items":  ["hello" "goodbye",]}
```

It appears to use some set of heuristics to make this work and in this one case I think did "the right thing."  But the fact that it did so silently is quite concerning as I don't know what I can trust for behavior.

Older versions of JSON.NET (6.x) throw an error, but newer versions (9.x) DO NOT.  Also, just using the non-generic version of Deserialize() will complain about the syntax error -- it's just the generic one that doesn't.

I tried to post a repro on dotnetfiddle but that doesn't work because dotnetfiddle always loads version 6.x of JSON.NET even if you ask for a different version.  (See https://dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/forums/228764--net-fiddle-ideas/suggestions/10782315-load-the-specified-version-of-json-net-rather-than).

So, here is a full repro (including code that prints out the version of Netwonsoft.Json.Dll being used).  It prints 2 (because it "successfully" parses the JSON) under the 9x versions of JSON.NET.  Under the 6.x ones it throws an error (as I think it should).

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(typeof(JsonConvert).Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(JsonConvert).Assembly.FullName);

        // I think this JSON is invalid because (1) it is missing a comma between the two values and (2) there is an extra comma at the end
        string json = @"{""Items"":  [""hello"" ""goodbye"",]}";

        // This deserialize is successful and produces an object with two values for Items
        Container result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(result.Items.Length + " items");
    }
}


public class Container
{
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Is this behavior documented and/or common practice?

Is there a way to force errors in this case?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem -- see https://dotnetfiddle.net/cVrpPp.  If I try to deserialize your JSON I see `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'Fields[2]', line 6, position 3.]` which is what one would expect.  What version of Json.NET are you using?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem, even back to 5.0.8. It's not valid JSON and, assuming your implementation allows this, it's not conforming to the "standard". About the only way I can think this *could* work is if you've put different but similar quote marks in your code (such as U+2033).

Comment: Possibly the example JSON is bad and OP really wants to know how to catch a [trailing comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209757/how-can-i-detect-invalid-json-containing-a-trailing-comma-with-c)?

Comment: Wow.  Well I am delighted to hear it doesn't repro even though I thought I had debugged through it.  I will try to pull together a complete repro that can be shared (or answer my own question with what I learned).

Comment: Why don't you post a reproducable code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ ??

Comment: I updated with a full repro and more detailed analysis which explains why others were not able to repro.  I'm still stumped :-(

Answer (score 0):

I [asked about this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1162#issuecomment-271720337)
 in the JSON.NET GitHub project.  It turns out that this is by design.  The response from James Newton-King was:

> JsonTextReader accepts trailing commas. 
>   There isn't a setting to change it up but you could role 
>   your own stricter JsonReader implementation.